# ModelMapper - DTO to Immutable

Tags: java, dto, modelmapper

I am mapping a Dto to a domain object. The domain is immutable and therefore has no no-arg constructor, which ModelMapper complains about.

Is there anyway for to make ModelMapper construct the object via a constructor and not setters?

My Dto has 6 member variables but my domain has 2 less (same names and types) so I'm guessing constructor creation might not be straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

This example configures a ModelMapper to allow private fields to be matched, therefore you do not need setters or getters nor constructors to map objects:

```
ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
           .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
           .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
```

Source: Configuration Examples in http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/

Comment: how do I use the skip method in this case? It needs a setter method, by default.

Answer (score -2):

Try to use a [ModelMapper Converter](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/converters/)

This way, you control how the destination object is created given the source object.